# In my spring boot application I am saving time in GMT timezone but data is getting stored in UTC timezone in database

Tags: spring-boot

This is the code where I am using the GMT timezone. I am saving the data at 2:00 pm but it is showing 8:30 am in database.

```
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=GMT&connectionTimeZone=GMT&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password: Password
```

Comment: Can you verify form which package you are importing the date class? we have Date in utills as well as in sql package, just verify that and import it as per requirement

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Actually, I am using Timestamp to save the particular data.

Comment: Please add the code on how you are saving the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your springboot application main class.

```
/*setting timezone to GMT*/
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
}
```

Also add the below property in your application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=GMT
```

this property will instruct Hibernate to use the provided time zone when reading and writing timestamp column values.

Comment: I added this method but it did not work .

Comment: your application is getting started with GMT timezone , check if your application is getting started with defaulttimezone as GMT.

Comment: after adding "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=GMT" it started working. Thank you @Rishal